# reactjs: getting error after importing headroom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in react and in my react application I'm trying to use "React Headroom" but after importing I'm getting this SyntaxError "Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (10:20):"

```
import React from 'react';
import Headroom from 'react-headroom/src';

import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Headroom>
        <nav>
          ...
        </nav>
      </Headroom>
    </div>
  );
}
```

export default App;

Comment: Are you using any css loader in you webpack file ? Because import .css will only works if you are using style-loader and css-loader in your webpack configurations.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of react with css modules

Comment: Usually you don't import from the `src` directory. Try to import from just 'react-headroom'.

Comment: yes actually it automotically imported from '/src' folder and that was the reason

Comment: Great @HovhannesGevorgyan. I've created an answer from my comment. Could you mark it as the correct solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Converting comment to answer*

Usually you don't import from the `src` directory.
Try to import from just `'react-headroom'`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`syntax-class-properties` plugin](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-class-properties/). Install it using

```
yarn add babel-plugin-syntax-class-properties
```

then add it to your `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "plugins": ["syntax-class-properties"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you are using correct plugins in your .babelrc file

```
 "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
  },
```